# 8 byte missing on EVP_DecryptFinal

Tags: c, openssl

this is my first question so please tell me if I do something wrong :).

My problem is I use

```
EVP_DecryptInit(&ctx1, EVP_des_ecb(), tmpkey, NULL);
EVP_DecryptUpdate(&ctx1, keysigout, &outlu ,keysigin, keysigfilelength);
EVP_DecryptFinal(&ctx1, keysigout, &outlf);
printf("DECLEN:%i",outlu + outlf);
```

to decrypt a binary file. The file is 248 bytes long but the printf only tells me EVP decrypted 240 bytes. keysigfilelength is 248 and should tell the update that 248 bytes need to be decrypted.

I dont understand why this doesnt work and would be happy if you can enlighten me.

Edit:
I just encrypted a file manually with the command

```
openssl enc -e -des-ecb -in test.txt -out test.bin -K 00a82b209cbeaf00
```

and it grew by 8 bytes :O. I still don't know where they come from but I don't think the general error I have in my program is caused by this.

The context of this whole problem is an information security course at my university. We got similar Tasks with different algorithms, but even someone who has done his program successfully couldnt figure out where the problem in my program is.

Is it ok to post my whole program for you?

Comment: Just to make sure, it's not something like being on Windows and opening the file in text mode so that '\r's are removed?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/H3riQhm7 here is a hexdump -C of the file. all work is done in linux

Comment: I thought it wouldn't be that, but better to be sure.

Comment: Are any of these functions returning an error?

Comment: No I check all return values.

Comment: How large is your programme? Try making it as small as possible while retaining the undesired behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope its fine to answer my own question.

```
EVP_DecryptUpdate(&ctx1, keysigout, &outlu ,keysigin, keysigfilelength);
EVP_DecryptFinal(&ctx1, keysigout + outlu, &outlf);
```

The problem was the missing outlu, DecryptFinal tried to decrypt the whole block again. When i added the outlu i got 7 byte in outlf, and it worked.
For future reference i add the whole function below.
It expects the key and iv to be one block of data.

```
int decrypt(const EVP_CIPHER *cipher,unsigned char *key, unsigned char *encryptedData, int encryptedLength,unsigned int * length, unsigned char ** decryptedData)
{
  int decryptedLength = 0, lastDecryptLength = 0, ret;
  unsigned char * iv = NULL;
  EVP_CIPHER_CTX *cryptCtx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
  EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(cryptCtx);
  *decryptedData = malloc (encryptedLength * sizeof(char));

  if(cipher->iv_len != 0) iv = key + cipher->key_len;

  EVP_DecryptInit_ex(cryptCtx, cipher, NULL, key, iv);
  EVP_DecryptUpdate(cryptCtx, *decryptedData, &decryptedLength, encryptedData, encryptedLength);
  ret = EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(cryptCtx, *decryptedData + decryptedLength, &lastDecryptLength);

  *length = decryptedLength + lastDecryptLength;

  EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(cryptCtx);
  EVP_cleanup();
  return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because block ciphers only really want to work on an input that is a multiple of their block size, the input is normally padded to meet this requirement. 
The default for many programs (including `openssl enc` is to use [PKCS #5 padding](http://www.rsa.com/products/bsafe/documentation/cryptoj35html/doc/dev_guide/group__CJ__SYM__PAD.html)

If the plaintext is not a multiple of 8 bytes then padding bytes are added so that it is. If it is already a multiple of 8 bytes then 8 bytes of padding are added. Thus it is entirely normal for the encrypted data to be longer than the plaintext.

Comment: my plaintext was 248 byte and he still adds 8 byte

Comment: If the plaintext is 248 bytes, 8 bytes are added - my wording wasn't very clear